# Does AVPlayer support .m3u8 format in tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer, avplayeritem

In my tvOS app. We are using the `.m3u8` format supported video. We are facing a strange problem in video play. When we are playing the video and when I trigger a system popup (i.e. Hold "HOME" to bring up the "SLEEP/CANCEL" popup, or an In-App Purchase confirmation prompt), and click on cancel button, in this condition video play fine. If you disconnect from the network the video will stop but progress bar in continuous running mode.

I am not understand where is a problem.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You ask if the format is supported in your title, but it sounds like the video is playing in your question. What is the issue? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Deniel Storm ,Actually this issue is occurring with .m3u8 format video and it is ok with .Mp4 format.